# Karma don't capture IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, karma-runner

I've got an issue with Karma running on IE8.

When i start Karma, Karma launch IE8 but wait on `Karma Starting ...`

The browser is never connected so i've got a timeout and the browser is kill.

I've set `IE_BIN` variable but no change !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh My !

I've got the solution ! I post it for future persons interest by this.

In fact it seems be a pretty socket.io bug !

In IE8 websockets systems is not suppport and Karma use Socket.io to communicate with the browser !

So Socket.io get a fallback system for old browsers...

By default if the browser is too old it's the flash system that is use !

So in IE8 it's through the Adobe Flash ActiveX plugin.

If i disable this plugin it works !

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is still relevant considering the question was posted few years ago. Just in case if anyone is trying to launch karma on IE, one can use: 
`karma-ie-launcher`

A proper way of using it is documented here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-ie-launcher. Hope it helps.